# "Single View Application" or "Tabbed Application" for iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, textview, viewcontroller

I would like to create an app for iOS (iPhone, iPad) with Xcode. It'll have three WebViews (two of them will open a pdf file) and a ViewController with a TextView integrated in it.  Can I work with "Tabbed Application" or would it be better to use "Single View Application"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabbed application would be better for this app, You can create 4 tabs with 4 ViewControllers.

3 of them would be ViewControllers with a UIWebview in them, and the other one can be the ViewController with the TextView

Comment: Only three? Are you sure?